# OAuth with google, but no domain name

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up OAuth 2.0 with google, however it prompts me to first set up a `OAuth consent screen`. It requires that you have a long running web server, along with its domain name(ip address only won't work). However I'm just trying to experiment some small scripts for personal uses. I don't have a domain name. How can I set up a OAuth without going through this verification?

Comment: What do you mean by temporary oauth?

Comment: @DaImTo You are right this wording is vague. I have editied it.